Find the value of integration: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,\infty)}{\frac{x}{1+x^{n}}\, \mathrm{d}x}$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^{n}}\,\mathrm dx}$$
Consider the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^n} \,\mathrm dx$$
This is an improper integral, but we can solve it using substitution or integration by parts.
Let $u = x^n$, then $\mathrm du = nx^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx$.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^n} \,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+u} \, \mathrm du$$
Now, integrate:
$$\frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+u} \,\mathrm du = \left.\frac{1}{n} \ln(1+u) \right|_{0}^{\infty}$$
Apply the limit as $n\to\infty$, the integral approaches:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left. \frac{1}{n} \ln(1+u) \right|_{0}^{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\infty)-\ln(1)}{n}$$
Simplify. Since $\ln(1+\infty)=\infty$, we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\infty}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \infty=0$$
The final answer is: $\boxed{0}$. Is my solution correct?

Hint: $\int_0^{1} \to \frac  12$ and $\int _1^{\infty} \to 0$. Both are quite easy.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. You miscalculated the effect of your substitution.

First notice that $\begin{cases}x^n\to 0&x<1\\x^n\to+\infty&x>1\end{cases}$
Therefore you need to split your integral into two parts $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^\infty$ to cope with the behaviour of $f(x)$ in each of these intervals.

on $[0,1]$ for $n\gg 1$ the function is not much different from $x$ so the integrals should be equivalent

$$\int_0^1\frac x{1+x^n}dx\sim\int_0^1 xdx=\frac 12$$
We can prove this directly with rough majorations
$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle\Bigg|\int_0^1\frac x{1+x^n}dx-\int_0^1 xdx\Bigg|&=\Bigg|\int_0^1\Big(\frac x{1+x^n}-x\Big)dx\Bigg|\\
&\le \int_0^1\Bigg|\frac {-x^{n+1}}{\underbrace{1+x^n}_{\ge 1}}\Bigg|dx\le\int_0^1x^{n+1}dx=\frac 1{n+2}\to 0
\end{align*}$$

on $[1,+\infty)$ for $n\gg 1$ the function is not much different from $\frac 1{x^{n-1}}$ so the integrals should be equivalent

$$\int_1^\infty\frac x{1+x^n}dx\sim\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^{n-1}}dx=\frac 1{n-2}\to 0$$
And we can also prove this directly with rough majorations
$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle\Bigg|\int_1^\infty\frac x{1+x^n}dx-\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^{n-1}}dx\Bigg|&=\Bigg|\int_1^\infty\Big(\frac x{1+x^n}-\frac 1{x^{n-1}}\Big)dx\Bigg|\\
&\le \int_1^\infty\Bigg|\frac {-1}{\underbrace{(1+x^n)}_{\ge\ x^n}x^{n-1}}\Bigg|dx\\
&\le\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^{2n-1}}dx=\frac 1{2n-2}\to 0\end{align*}$$
Note that $\frac 1{2n-2}$ is smaller than $\frac 1{n-2}$ so their difference is also going to zero and we does not loose the convergence (to zero) through addition/subtraction.

Therefore the resulting integral on whole domain $[0,\infty)$ is $\frac  12+0=\frac 12$


We can evaluate the integral in three parts.
Note first
$$
\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^1{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}.
$$
For the second part of the integral on RHS, by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem we have
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_1^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_1^{\infty}{\left( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{1+x^n} \right) \mathrm{d}x}=0.
$$
Now for the first part, take $\epsilon>0$ arbitarily small, then we may write
$$
\int_0^1{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}.
$$
Now
$$
\mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}\le \int_0^{1-\epsilon}{x\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\left( 1-\epsilon \right) ^2}{2}
$$
and
$$
\mathop {\lim\mathrm{inf}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}\ge \mathop {\lim\mathrm{inf}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{x}{1+\left( 1-\epsilon \right) ^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^{1-\epsilon}{x\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\left( 1-\epsilon \right) ^2}{2}
$$
together with $\epsilon\to 0^+$ gives
$$
\int_0^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Now for the last part, we have
$$
\int_{1-\epsilon}^1{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}\le \int_{1-\epsilon}^1{\frac{1}{1+\left( 1-\epsilon \right) ^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\epsilon}{1+\left( 1-\epsilon \right) ^n}\rightarrow 0,
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

We can use complex integration
$$f(z) = \frac{z}{1+z^n}$$
this function has singularities for
$$1+z^n = 0 \iff z_k = e^{i(\pi/n + 2k\pi/n)}, \ k = 0,1,\dots,n-1$$
we can consider the following integration path, where $R>0$ is supposed sufficiently large to enclose one singularity
the only singularity inside the path is $z = e^{i\pi/n}$ so the integral for the residue theorem is
$$\oint f(z) dz = 2\pi i \ \text{Res}_f(e^{i\pi/n})$$
which is not that difficult to evaluate
$$\text{Res}_f(e^{i\pi/n}) = \frac{e^{i2\pi/n}}{n}$$
Now we can estimate the integral on $A_R$
$$\begin{align*}
\bigg | \int_{A_R} f(z) dz \bigg| &= \bigg | \int_{0}^{2\pi/n} f(Re^{i\theta})Ri \ e^{i\theta} d\theta \bigg|\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{2\pi/n} |f(Re^{i\theta})| R d\theta \\
&\leq \frac{2\pi}{n}\frac{1}{R^{n-1}} \to 0 \quad \text{if $n\geq 2,R\to \infty$}
\end{align*}$$
while
$$\begin{align*}\int_{L'_R}f(z)dz &= \int_{R}^{0}f(te^{2\pi i /n})e^{2\pi i /n}dt\\
&= -e^{4\pi i /n}\int_{0}^{R} \frac{t}{1+t^n}dt =: I
\end{align*}$$
$J = \lim_{R\to \infty}I$ is the integral we are trying to evaluate. For what shown above
$$J -e^{4\pi i /n} J = 2\pi i \frac{e^{i2\pi/n}}{n}\\
J = \frac{2\pi i}{n(e^{3\pi i /n}-e^{-\pi i /n})}$$
In the end
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} J = \frac{1}{2}$$

noted that:
$$
\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}dx=\frac{\pi}{m\sin \left( \frac{n+1}{m}\pi \right)}}\,\,  m>n+1>0
$$
maybe you can use gamma function and beta function to prove it,It's easy.
so
$$
I=\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}dx}
\\
\,\, =\frac{\pi}{n\sin \left( \frac{2}{n}\pi \right)}
$$
so
$$
\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{\pi}{n\sin \left( \frac{2}{n}\pi \right)}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Note
$$
\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^1{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\overset{x\to1/x}{\mathrm{d}x}=}\int_0^1{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_0^{1}{\frac{x^{n-3}}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^1{\frac{x+x^{n-3}}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}
$$
and hence
$$ \bigg|\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}-\int_0^1x\mathrm{d}x\bigg|=\bigg|\int_0^{1}{\frac{x+x^{n-3}}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}-\int_0^1x\mathrm{d}x\bigg|=\bigg|\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-3}-x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x\bigg|\le \int_0^1(x^{n-3}+x^{n+1})\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{n-2}+\frac{1}{n+2}. $$
So
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^1x\mathrm{d}x=\frac12.$$

If $u = x^n$, then $x = \sqrt[n]{u}$, so
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^n} \, \mathrm{d}x
=
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+u} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{n x^{n-1}}
=
\frac 1 n \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2-n}}{1+u} \, \mathrm{d}u 
=
\frac 1 n \int_0^\infty \frac{u^{\frac 2 n -1}}{1+u} \, \mathrm{d}u 
$$
rendering your calculation incorrect.
Indeed, you will probably make no work via traditional Calculus I/II techniques since Wolfram suggests the function has a nonelementary antiderivative, so you'll need to be more clever.

It is also easy to see that, graphically, as $n \to \infty$ the integral will be nonzero, since the integrand looks like this for $n=100$:

And this should be obvious: for $x$ small and $n$ large, $1+x^n \approx 1$. But if $x > 1$, then $x^n$ becomes very large for large $n$, so the integrand becomes very small very fast.

This limiting graph does however suggest other approaches may work, e.g. dominated convergence.

why is this massively downvoted ? it doesn't giver the answer but provides interesting remarks.
